# How to make widgets receive QMouseEvent when cursor is upon it if QMenu pops up?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

When a QMenu's instance pops up as below, only menu can receive mouseMoveEvent.

```
def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
    '''
        some code
    '''
    menu.exec_(event.globalPos())
```

But i want other widgets can behave like if the menu wasn't there. It means a widget can receive mouseMoveEvent if the cursor is upon it.

I know my purpose can be achieved because some apps have already achieved.But i don't know the correct way in Qt.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

One way should be to install an QEventHandler on the QMenu which receives all 
the Events before they reach the Menu. You can then inspect the event type and send it in case of Mouse events directly to the widget.

You may have issues with mouse coordinates but there are alwas ways (like global x and y) to map to the correct widget relative coordinates.

Simple Example (c++ but python would be more or less the same):

```
void MyClass::init() {
   m_menu->installEventFilter(this);
}

bool MyClass::eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * event) {
   // filter the events you are interested in ...
   if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress) {
      // at this point you may need to alter the coordinates, not sure, just try
      // send the event to your mouseEventHandling method
      this->mousePressEvent(event);
   } else {
      // this will stop any further handling of this event (the menu itself will not receive it)
      // change to false if the menu shall work as usual
      return true;
   }
   // this will trigger regular event handling for all other events
   return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Also see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter

To handle all events yourself and distribute as needed, consider a transparent widget overlaying everything whose events you can filter. (You can put multiple widgets in one and the same grid layout cell).

Comment: Thanks for help. Aaron Hillegass is my first English teacher in reading CS books. It will be very pleasure to see you, Aaron.Maybe your method can help me with one widget to receive mouseEvent which constructs a menu.But my purpose is that all widget in my app can get the mouseMove event just like the way Window Manager manages them.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Is there any link which explains how to do it?